# Editable Combo Box Javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, combobox

I need to do the following thing:
Using **JavaScript**, the **HTML input tag** having the text type and a **select tag** (combo box), create an editable combo box.

I have no idea how to make a combo box editable. Can you give me some suggestions, please?

I create the combo box like this, but is obviously not editable:

```
<html>
    <label>Your preferred programming language: </label>
    <select id="combobox">
        <option value="">Select one...</option>
        <option value="ActionScript">ActionScript</option>
        <option value="AppleScript">AppleScript</option>
    </select>
</html>
```

Where should I use the input tag?

Comment: It's good practice to accept an answer or ask for futher assistance if none of the answers are suitable :)

Answer (score 10):

HTML5 includes the `datalist` element which solves this problem! :)

```html
<html>
    <label>Your preferred programming language: </label>
    <input type="text" list="combo-options" id="combobox">
    <datalist id="combo-options">
        <option value="ActionScript">ActionScript</option>
        <option value="AppleScript">AppleScript</option>
    </datalist>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<label>Your preferred programming language: </label>
<input type="text" id="new_value"/>
<select id="combobox">
    <option value="">Select one...</option>
    <option value="ActionScript">ActionScript</option>
    <option value="AppleScript">AppleScript</option>
</select>



$("#new_value").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) { // enter key
        var value = $(e.currentTarget).val();   // store the value from the input tag
        var option = $("<option/>");            // create a new option tag
        option.val(value).text(value);          // set the value attribute as well as the content
        $("#combobox").append(option);          // insert the new object to the dom
    }
});
```