# how to change the combo box to text when i select other in anyone of <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a code that list below option in . when i select other, then combo box should convert into text. i tried with some script using onchange fucntion

```js
function chargeother(ele){
   if(ele.value === "Other"){
    alert("i am inside other");
      document.getElementById("inputtype").innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" name=\"type\">";
     }    
}
```

. but its changing only one , but i would like to change where ever user select other in any of the

```html
<tr>
<td>
      <select name="inp"  id="inp" >
      <option name="S1">YES</option>
      <option name="S2">NO</option>
      <option name="S3">OK</option>
      <option name="S4">NOT OK</option>
        <option name="S5">Other</option>
      </select> 
</td>
<td>
      <select name="inp"  id="inp" >
      <option name="S1">YES</option>
      <option name="S2">NO</option>
      <option name="S3">OK</option>
      <option name="S4">NOT OK</option>
        <option name="S5">Other</option>
      </select> 
</td>
<td>
      <select name="inp"  id="inp" >
      <option name="S1">YES</option>
      <option name="S2">NO</option>
      <option name="S3">OK</option>
      <option name="S4">NOT OK</option>
        <option name="S5">Other</option>
      </select> 
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What have your tried so far? show us some javascript.

Comment: what have you tried until now? what should happen to the data? will it be submitted?...? please add some more context.

Comment: You can look at `datalist` here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36681191/editable-combo-box-javascript-and-html

Comment: @A.Lau yes its really useful :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- add value attribute to each `<option>` tag
- `select` `onchange`, check the value of the select
- if it is other(in this case s5), use replacechild

[ **[EDIT]** as per OP's comment]
you can pass the `this` to the `function` to identify which element is changed and also for *code reusability* (one code for all similar behaviours).
The `id` which we need to apply to new `input` is taken from the `this` keyword in function definition.
In each `select` tag, add the following attribute *as I did in the code below*

```
onchange="check(this);"
```

and in `function` definition, use

```
function check(elm){ // elm holds the changed select tag
elm.value // will return the value of currently changed element
elm.getAttribute('id') // will return the id of the current attribute, which we use later to apply to input
```

See the code below

```js
function check(elm){
  if(elm.value=="s5"){
    var inp=document.createElement('input');
      inp.setAttribute('type','text');
      inp.setAttribute('id',elm.getAttribute('id'));
      inp.setAttribute('name','inp');
    elm.parentNode.replaceChild(inp,elm);
  }
}
```

```html
<td>
<select name="inp"  id="inp" onchange="check(this);">
  <option value='s1' name="S1">YES</option>
  <option value='s2' name="S2">NO</option>
  <option value='s3' name="S3">OK</option>
  <option value='s4' name="S4">NOT OK</option>
    <option value='s5' name="S5">Other</option>
  </select>
    <select name="inp"  id="inp2" onchange="check(this);">
  <option value='s1' name="S1">YES</option>
  <option value='s2' name="S2">NO</option>
  <option value='s3' name="S3">OK</option>
  <option value='s4' name="S4">NOT OK</option>
    <option value='s5' name="S5">Other</option>
  </select>
    <select name="inp"  id="inp3" onchange="check(this);">
  <option value='s1' name="S1">YES</option>
  <option value='s2' name="S2">NO</option>
  <option value='s3' name="S3">OK</option>
  <option value='s4' name="S4">NOT OK</option>
    <option value='s5' name="S5">Other</option>
  </select>
    </td>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works! but if i have 3 set of above set of select <td>  in a single row, if user select other anyone of <td>, it should into text box. but in this case only one i can get.

Comment: Please wait. I will give solution once i reached my office. Now I am on way.

Comment: could u please share your idea

Comment: @Jsel , thanks for waiting my friend. I updated the code. You can check it now.

Comment: Thanks a lot! let me try with this

Comment: anytime :-). it will work if it is placed in same td or different td or even in different tr.

Comment: Anytime :-) @Jsel

Answer (score 2):

```
 1. Instead of creating a new tag element 
 2. we can just replace the existing select tag to input tag
 3. Pros of using this method will reduce the script.

Refer this [plunker][1] for further information.


  [1]: https://plnkr.co/edit/2ZztfpmvAhJZMQGtgZPw?p=preview
```

Answer (score 1):

Or something like this with jQuery:

```js
$('#inp').change(function() {
  if (this.value === 'S5') {
    $(this).replaceWith('<input name="inp" type="text">')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="inp" id="inp">
  <option value="S1">YES</option>
  <option value="S2">NO</option>
  <option value="S3">OK</option>
  <option value="S4">NOT OK</option>
  <option value="S5">Other</option>
</select>
```

Or in pure JS also easy:

```js
document.querySelector('#inp').addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (this.value === 'S5') {
    this.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<input type="text" name="inp">')
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this)
  }
})
```

```html
<select name="inp" id="inp">
  <option value="S1">YES</option>
  <option value="S2">NO</option>
  <option value="S3">OK</option>
  <option value="S4">NOT OK</option>
  <option value="S5">Other</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<select name="inp"  id="inp" >
        <option value="S1">YES</option>
        <option value="S2">NO</option>
        <option value="S3">OK</option>
        <option value="S4">NOT OK</option>
    <option value="S5">Other</option>
</select> 
<input id='box' type="text" />

$( "#inp" )
  .change(function () {
    $( "#inp option:selected" ).each(function() {
      if($( this ).text() == "Other"){
          $("#box").show();
          $('#inp').hide()
      }else{
        $("#box").hide();
      }
    });
  })
  .change();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/russellmazonde/1j0058x7/4/)

Comment: how you think that it will check value even without setting the value attribute to option?